# Django Error Message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a case. Once the form is submitted, it has to make a query. If the query exists, it has to send an error message. If the query does not exist, it has to save the data. I have written view as below and it works. But the only issue is that the error message goes like a success message. I have tried placing the query before validating the form, still, it's same. How could I resolve this?

```
def permissionFormView(request):
    r_form = forms.RoleForm()
    p_form = forms.PermissionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = forms.PermissionForm(request.POST)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            role = p_form.cleaned_data['role_name']
            feature = p_form.cleaned_data['feature']
            if models.PermissionModel.objects.filter(role_name=role,feature=feature).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Permission exists.')
            else:
                p_form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Permission added successfully.')
                return render(request, 'company_profile.html', {'r_form': r_form, 'p_form': p_form})
    return render(request,'company_profile.html',{'r_form':r_form,'p_form':p_form})
```

Client Side Form Code:

```
<form action="{% url 'permission_form' %}" novalidate method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <label for="r_name"><small><strong>{{ p_form.role_name.label }}</strong></small></label>
        <p>{{p_form.role_name}}</p>
        {% for error in p_form.role_name.errors %}
        <p><small class="alert-danger">{{ error }}</small></p>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        <label for="r_feature"><small><strong>{{ p_form.feature.label }}</strong></small></label>
        <p>{{p_form.feature}}</p>
        {% for error in p_form.feature.errors %}
        <p><small class="alert-danger">{{ error }}</small></p>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        <label for="permission"><small><strong>{{ p_form.permission.label }}</strong></small></label>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="permission" name="permission"
        {% if r_form.role_name.value is not None %}
        value="{{ p_form.permission.value }}"
        {% endif %}
        ></p>
        {% for error in p_form.permission.errors %}
        <p><small class="alert-danger">{{ error }}</small></p>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' value='Save'>
</form>
```

Image of various error messages:
[image: error screenshots] 
All I want is to show the Permission exists message like an error in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put that into the form's `clean` method so that it is run along with all the other form validation logic.

```
class PermissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        role = self.cleaned_data['role_name']
        feature = self.cleaned_data['feature']
        if models.PermissionModel.objects.filter(role_name=role,feature=feature).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Permission exists.')
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. The clean method is what I had to use and it worked. The code is slightly changed though. Using: self.cleaned_data['role_name'] throws a key error. Instead, I used  role = self.cleaned_data.get('role_name')  and everything is fine now. Thank you, sir.